# Math.random() Generates same number

Tags: java, random

I'm writing a generic snake game in Java, and I want my apple to be drawn at random coordinates on call. However, when I set my coordinates based off Math.random(), both coordinates create the same Math.random result. This means the apple is always drawn on a linear line ex. (4,4)

```
//Draws apple
public void drawApple(Graphics2D gfx) {
    rectCoords(gfx, red, (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*20), (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*20));
}
// rectCoords(graphics, color, xcoordinate, ycoordinate)
```

I assume this is because they're using the same time value for their seed, since they were called at the same time.

I've tried `Math.random()`, `Random` objects, even a combination of both. I've tried declaring them as variables at different times throughout the code, even throwing in a `Thread.sleep();` (although I had some trouble actually getting it to work).

Surely I'm not the only one who's tried to generate two random numbers at the same time. I appreciate anyone who looks this over or points me to a similar thread. Thanks!

EDIT: I fixed it, it was a problem in another piece of code. Although, not really sure how to close this thread or mark it resolved...

Comment: Are you *sure* the code you're running is the same as the code you've posted here?

Comment: Math.random() gives a double value which is >0 and <1, which when you convert to integer it will always becomes 0

Comment: What is the same numbers you are getting? is it always 0?

Comment: Are you *sure* you've using `java.lang.Math` (and you haven't imported another class called `Math`?

Comment: Hum. That's *very* intriguing. Be assured they are *not* called at the same time: that's not how Java works when evaluating function argument lists. Note also that Math.random() doesn't work well in a multi-threaded environment. Personally though, I think you have a bug in your rectCoords function: you're discarding one of the arguments.

Comment: I'm going to use my psychic powers...

You have a typo in your `rectCoords` method; you have coded either `xcoordinate` twice or `ycoordinate` twice, when you meant to use both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will always get a number which is less than 20 with your current code (because Math.random() gives a double value which is >=0 and <1), so instead you can use `nextInt()` method from `java.util.Random` as shown below:

```
public void drawApple(Graphics2D gfx) {
     Random random = new Random();
    rectCoords(gfx, red, random.nextInt(), random.nextInt());
}
```

Also, you can actually use the overloaded method `nextInt(maxNumber)` to set the maximum limit to the random number by using/passing maxNumber value `random.nextInt(maxNumber)`.

Comment: Not true, the result is multiplied by 20, which is promoted to a `double` type; all prior to truncation to an `int`.

Comment: So what? OP is multiplying by `20`, so the result will be `0 <= x < 20`

Comment: yes, thanks, I mean the same >=0, corrected